# gss_accept_sec_context() error:ASN.1 structure is missing a required field

Tags: kerberos

I'm trying to implement Kerberos authentication on Ubuntu.

run_kerberos_server.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

docker stop krb5-server && docker rm krb5-server && true

docker run -d --network=altexy --name krb5-server \
  -e KRB5_REALM=EXAMPLE.COM -e KRB5_KDC=localhost -e KRB5_PASS=12345 \
  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
  -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro \
   --network-alias example.com \
  -p 88:88 -p 464:464 -p 749:749 gcavalcante8808/krb5-server

echo "=== Init krb5-server docker container ==="
docker exec krb5-server /bin/sh -c "
# Create users bob as normal user
# and add principal for the service
cat << EOF  | kadmin.local
add_principal -randkey \"HTTP/service.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM\"
ktadd -k /etc/krb5-service.keytab -norandkey \"HTTP/service.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM\"
ktadd -k /etc/admin.keytab -norandkey \"admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM\"
listprincs
quit
EOF
"

echo "=== Copy keytabs  ==="
docker cp krb5-server:/etc/krb5-service.keytab "${DIR}"/krb5-service.keytab
docker cp krb5-server:/etc/admin.keytab "${DIR}"/admin.keytab
```

Get Kerberos ticket:

```
alex@alex-secfense:~/projects/proxy-auth/etc/kerberos$ kinit admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM: 
alex@alex-secfense:~/projects/proxy-auth/etc/kerberos$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: admin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
16.12.2020 12:05:38  17.12.2020 00:05:38  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 17.12.2020 12:05:35
```

Then I start nginx, also in Docker container, image is derived from `openresty/openresty:xenial`.
My `/etc/hosts` file has `127.0.0.1 service.example.com` line.

My Firefox is configured for `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` = `service.example.com`

I open `service.example.com:<mapped_port> page in Firefox, nginx responds with 401 and Firefox send` Authorization: Negotiate ...` header.

My server side code (error and result handling is stripped):

```
MYAPI int authenticate(const char* token, size_t length)
{
    gss_buffer_desc service = GSS_C_EMPTY_BUFFER;
    gss_name_t my_gss_name = GSS_C_NO_NAME;
    gss_cred_id_t my_gss_creds = GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL;

    OM_uint32 minor_status;
    OM_uint32 major_status;
    gss_ctx_id_t gss_context = GSS_C_NO_CONTEXT;
    gss_name_t client_name = GSS_C_NO_NAME;
    gss_buffer_desc output_token = GSS_C_EMPTY_BUFFER;

    gss_buffer_desc input_token = GSS_C_EMPTY_BUFFER;
    input_token.length = length;
    input_token.value = (void*)token;

    major_status = gss_accept_sec_context(&minor_status, &gss_context, my_gss_creds, &input_token,
            GSS_C_NO_CHANNEL_BINDINGS, &client_name, NULL, &output_token, NULL, NULL, NULL);

     return 0;
}
```

Eventually, I get `gss_accept_sec_context() error:ASN.1 structure is missing a required field` error.

The same code works great with Windows Kerberos setup.

Any idea what does it mean or how to debug the issue?

I did define `KRB5_TRACE=/<log_file_name>` environment variable and see lines like below:

```
[7] 1607798057.341744: Sending request (937 bytes) to EXAMPLE.COM
[6] 1608109670.292389: Sending request (937 bytes) to EXAMPLE.COM
[6] 1608109670.660887: Sending request (937 bytes) to EXAMPLE.COM
```

May it be DNS issue?

UPDATE: I missed that I specify keyatb file to use on server side before calling `gss_accept_sec_context` (again error handling is stripped out):

```
OM_uint32 major_status = gsskrb5_register_acceptor_identity(keytab_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You code breaks the fundemantal concept of context completion. It violates RFC 7546 and is not trustworthy, plus you completely ignore major/minor. Now, you tokens get modified somehow in-flight because the ASN.1 encoding is broken.

- Dump token before and after transmission and compare.
- Start with `gss-server` and `gss-client` first.
- Read their code and implement your alike. Do not deviate from the imperative of the context look completion,
- Show the ticket cache after Firefox has obtained a service ticket.

As soon as you have to tokens, display inspect them with https://lapo.it/asn1js/.

Comment: You didn't read the question - `error and result handling is stripped` `The same code works great with Windows Kerberos setup`,

Comment: https://lapo.it/asn1js/. successfully parse the token

Comment: curiously, gss-server does exacltly the same

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler I did that, and still wnat to stress this out that people should NOT take this as an example. Did you try gss-server?